# Exchange 2013 mail bounce

Tags: windows, email, exchange

On our exchange 2013 mailserver there are mail accounts that are active.
But one sender can not send mails and they bounce with NDR

```
OnePostBox@DomainOnServer.com
host mail01.MailServer.com [111.222.333.444]
SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined sending data block:
550 5.1.1 User unknown
```

I really do not know what or where to look at this point.

Comment: What is the scenario, internal user send to external domain user or external user send to internal domain user?
Do other senders have this issue or only this specific one in the sender domain? According your log, it seems the sender may be blocked. If internal user cannot receive the mail, you may check the configuration in your organization. Go to the user mailbox properties, click the “Message Delivery Restrictions” in “mailbox features” tab, check if there are any restrictions.

Comment: Scenario is : external user sending to a group of internal users in the same domain. In between there is the spam protection gateway but its logs confirms the same user unknown. The mailboxes are actively receiving emails from other mail adresses without any problem at all,

Answer (score 0):

"User unknown" means there is no such user on the destination server (does not exist or it is disabled). There's nothing else to this.

If you are certain that there is no user problem, it seems that the transmission gets lost somewhere, although the error suppose to be different in this case.

Here's a few things to try :

- On your ISA Server, under configurations-add-ins-applications, turn off the SMTP filter.
- If you use Cisco Firewalls, remove ESMTP inspection and disable Intrusion Detection
- If you use Watchguard,  disable SMTP Proxy filtering

Practically, make sure that any security measure you use does not interfere with SMTP.

Comment: unfortunately it was not that simple in this case because the user exists. And Actively receiving mails and sending.

Comment: It is strange because in case of other problems the error should be time out, not use unknown. I'm adding a few things to the answer.

Comment: unfortunately I can not take down security because there are thousands of customers on it. liability would be too great. the mail is sent to a group of addresses in the same domain. In that group some of the mail adresses do not exit but 90% of them exists. And the existing ones also get error.

Comment: You can either turn off security for testing, or dig into it and see why it is actually blocked. Maybe there was a security reason behind the error.

Comment: I got an full NDR report but unfortunately it was did not include anything new....

Comment: What happened when sending via OWA? If it works in OWA, maybe you could try online mode or update the OAB in Outlook client. In addition, check the configure in “delivery management” option.

Comment: An OWA test could be relevant as it can determine if it's a client problem or not.

Comment: Our server is on the receiving side. But when i check messagetracking logs I see that Mailboxes are actively receiving. Only from one sender we have this problem.